# Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and C#. This is a function that is being called form elsewhere in my console program, but I can't seem to get input into the array `ipoints`.

```
static void GetPoints(int ipoints, string srestaurant)
{
    int index = 0;
    int iinput;
    for (index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        Console.Write("please enter how many points " + srestaurant[index] + " got : ");
        iinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while (iinput < 0 && iinput > 20)
        {
            Console.Write("please enter how many points " + srestaurant[index] + " got : ");
            iinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        ipoints[index] = iinput;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare ipoints as an array of ints, not just an int.

Change `int ipoints` to `int[] ipoints`.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use an `int` like an `int[]` array.

Here:

```
static void GetPoints(int ipoints, string srestaurant)
//                    ^^^^^^ not an array
```

You're doing it here:

```
ipoints[index] = iinput;
//     ^^^^^^^ its not an array
```

Either make it an array, or rethink what you're trying to do.