# Cities Skylines Modding Remove all trees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cities-skylines-api

I am not sure how to do it.

```
foreach (uint tree in treesToDelete.m_trees)
{
    ?????
}
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < TreeManager.m_treeCount; i++)
{
    var tree = TreeManager.instance.m_trees[i];
    TreeManager.instance.ReleaseTree(tree);
}
```

Don't know how to finish the first one and I get these errors when I use the second.

An object reference is required to access non-static member TreeManager.m_treeCount
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Array32
The best overloaded method match for TreeManager.ReleaseTree(uint) has some invalid arguments

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Come on, I suck and I know that all three lines in the second part are wrong, I just want to show that I tried. Edited with errors...

Comment: To get help with using some api that isn't well-known, it'd be helpful to post a link to the documentation for said api.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for giving us the error.
You're getting two errors there:

> An object reference is required to access non-static member
>   TreeManager.m_treeCount'

You need to initialise the TreeManager class. [An object reference is required to access non-static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992681/an-object-reference-is-required-to-access-non-static-member)

`var treeManager = new TreeManager();`

I'm not sure if that takes constructor arguments. But that should help.

You can then access it like so:

```
var treeManager = new TreeManager();
for (int i = 0; i < treeManager.m_treeCount; i++)
        {
        var tree = treeManager.instance.m_trees[i];
        treeManager.instance.ReleaseTree(tree);
 }
```

Your second error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of typeArray32' The
>   best overloaded method match for `TreeManager.ReleaseTree(uint)' has
>   some invalid arguments

I think it's linked to the fact that TreeManager wasn't initialised, see here: [Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081690/error-1-cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-int)

Here is a good piece of documentation for the the API: https://github.com/cities-skylines/Assembly-CSharp/wiki/TreeManager

Comment: Yeah...no.. That's not it,

Comment: It doesn't, I'm trying to make the bomb tool. I'll stop.