# C# user int array declaration

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having issues with c# (new to it) but with some programming experience (not great, many moons ago, Python)

I must be doing something wrong and looking for the answer incorrect, spent a couple of days searching for this. I think its really simple and I must be doing something wrong.

Basically I want to take a user input of an interger and store it as an array so I perform maths on individual numbers. However, when I try and get the console to read the number I can not then access the 4th position etc because as c# keeps telling me.

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type int

what elemental mistake am I making here guys,

Edited to improve original question.

sorry all, that was a little vague. Let me show you how my idea works in python and maybe that would help matters. Basically, i'm trying to access the positions of an integer.

```
Number = (input("Please enter a Number number"))

check_digit = number[7]

loyalty = number[:-1]
```

I want the user to enter the number and then the program access different numbers in the array.

Comment: Are you just asking how to use arrays in C#?  I suspect some Googling and tutorials will provide you with a variety of useful examples.  What did you try?  How did it fail?  What result were you expecting?  Why?

Comment: No code, vote to close. Please don't expect people to be psychic. See this guideline in the SO Help Centre: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the exception, you probably declare you Array like this:

`int myArray;`

Instead of this:

`int[] myArray;`

[Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081690/error-1-cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-int)